# How to create a friends list in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friend-list

In Facebook, a "friends list is a sub-group of your friends that you can define. For instance, you can create a "jazz-toronto" friends list containing only people you want to invite when you play a jazz concert in Toronto.

The [How do I create a new list to organize my friends?](https://www.facebook.com/help/190416214359937) Facebook help page is explicit:

> To create a new list:
>   1. Scroll down to Friends on the left side of your News Feed. Hover over Friends and click More.
>   2. Click Create List.

**Problem:** I don't have a "Friends" label on the left side of my News Feed. I only have Favorites, Pages, Groups, Apps, Interests, Events, Developer.

**Question:** Where should I click, or what is the URL, to create a friends list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My friends list option is on the left hand side of the main page. The URL it links to is https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists/